# how to pass function returns as an argument for another function in polymer

Tags: polymer-1.0

```
<span> {{_x(_y(‘c’))}}</span>
```

This is not working on polymer do you know why?

X and y are declared in polymer x is working and y is working by themselves but not both as the above syntax

‘C’ in my actual code is a parameter in dom-repeat

Comment: What exactly try to do in dom-repeat. Filter for some condition or? I mean there are very smart and short solutions inside Polymer apart then js.